# Javascript, pass type as parameter in functions

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning Javascript and I noticed something that, to me, doesn't make much sense.

In an example on the ArcGIS website, there is this piece of code

```
var map
require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
  map = new Map("mapDiv", {
    center: [-56.049, 38.485],
    zoom: 3,
    basemap: "streets"
  });
});
```

I don't get how you can do "new Map" when Map is the parameter of function(Map). To be able to use new, then Map must be a type and I haven't seen a type being a parameter in other languages.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The funny thing about Javascript is that there really are no classes. The equivalent of a class in Javascript is just a special kind of function. Actually, forget about the "special" in the previous sentence (just wanted to soften the blow). *Any* function can "act as a class" and be instantiated with [the `new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) (although it is really only useful when that function assigns stuff to `this` so the generated object gains public methods and attributes).

And functions in Javascript are first-class citizens. Functions can be assigned to variables and functions can be passed as arguments to other functions. This makes it perfectly legal to pass a function to another function and then have that other function instantiate it with `new`.

Yes, this is indeed a very strange concept to wrap a head around which is used to class-oriented programming languages. But it becomes surprisingly intuitive once you understand it.

So what happens in the code you posted in the question is this:

1. When `require` is executed, it calles an anonymous function passing a <strike>class</strike> function to it
2. the anonymous function assigns that <strike>class</strike> function to a local variable `Map`
3. the anonymous function then creates an instance of that <strike>class</strike> function.
4. the instance is assigned to the global variable `map`

Comment: Ok so, in what happen if put code in the function and not just variables assignments? Will it execute when I do new Map?

Comment: I will take the suvroc example below with the Apple function. If there is code that modify the page, or let's say, an alert, will the alert show when I will do var apple = new Apple() ?

Comment: @Math yes, it will be executed. Think of it as a constructor in a class-based programming language. It *should* set up the object but it *can* theoretically do anything it wants.

Comment: I think that I get it now, since variables in the function are declared as they are assigned, that's why there are no classes since there is no variables declarations in Javascript. So calling a constructor (a function) with variables assignments (with this.) already act both as a class declaration + variables declaration + constructor. Is that it?

Comment: @Math almost. There actually are variable declarations in Javascript. The `var` keyword declares a local variable. Any variable you declare by assignment is a global variable and is something you should avoid if possible (in [strict mode javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) it is forbidden). In constructor-functions `var` can take the role of `private` variables, because locals can not be accessed from the outside but it can be accessed from any public functions declared in the style `this.getFoo = function() { return localVariable; }`

Answer (score 7):

> To be able to use new, then Map must be a type

No. For `new` to work, `Map` must be a **function**.

Functions are first class objects in JavaScript and can be treated like any other piece of data (assigned to variables, passed as function arguments, etc).

```js
function One() {
  this.foo = 1;
}

function myCallingThing(arg) {
  alert(new arg().foo + 1);
}

var Two = One;

var instance = new Two;

alert(instance.foo);

myCallingThing(Two);
```

This is not unique to JavaScript.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

sub example {
    say "Hello";
}

sub callme {
    my $var = shift;
    $var->();
}

callme(\&example);
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def example():
    print "Hello\n"

def callme(arg):
    arg();

callme(example)
```

Comment: Ok I think I get it. The python example seems more like a function pointer to me. I am familiar with this but the use of a function as a class (to use its own variables) is new to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

By defining function you can create something like class

```
function Apple (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";
    this.getInfo = getAppleInfo;
}
```

Then you can create new instance of your function/class

```
var apple = new Apple('lobo');
```

So your `Map` parameter is a function that define objects